# Where does the phrase "A Feast in Time of Plague" come from?

Tags: phrase-origin

What's the history of the phrase "A Feast in Time of Plague"? Is there such a common phrase in English at all? [Wikipedia says](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Feast_in_Time_of_Plague) that this is the title of Puskin's play, which is based of John Wilson's play "The City of Plague". Unfortunately, there is no wiki page on that play and I can't verify if that phrase is present in that piece by John Wilson. Anyway, even if it's not in there, was it already present in English language even before John Wilson?

Comment: Also well-known is the novel *Love in the Time of Cholera* by Gabriel GarcÍa Márquez

Comment: [The City of the Plague](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_City_of_the_Plague/FUIUAAAAYAAJ?hl=en) is available for free online, but I don't see any relevant results for "feast" in it. (It looks like Wikipedia has the name slightly wrong.)

Comment: @GEdgar - Thank you! Is this a common phrase in English? Or is there any similar idiomatic expression in English?

Comment: @Laurel - Thank you! Is this a common phrase in English? Or is there any similar idiomatic expression in English?

Comment: *Is this a common phrase in English?* No. It just seems to be a collocation of words. X at a time of Y" is no more than a rather poetic/literary way of saying X during Y.

Comment: Reminds me of [_**Christmas in Wartime**_](https://www.wob.com/en-gb/film/dvd/christmas-in-wartime-the-german-people-in-wartime-1939-1945/5060000036336?gclid=CjwKCAjwpqCZBhAbEiwAa7pXeQatTAT-8iKJ6x9CNNN0jngkTbh7wHDDWny9xaFfuwTfF81fDdpRmxoCg2sQAvD_BwE#DVDB0000DCXYVLN)

Comment: Incidentally, _etymology_ only occurs to words, not phrases. Nobody knows where phrases come from, unless they come with a story. Or get a story made up about them, which they normally do.

Comment: The Pushkin is in Russian and the Garcia Marquez is in Spanish, so we cannot conclude anything about **English** from those examples.

Comment: @GEdgar - The Pushkin's book is based of an English play "The City of Plague". I just wanted to know if that phrase (a feast in time of plague) or any idiomatic phrase similar to it is present in that book or in English language in general.

Comment: 'A feast in time of famine…' would seem to me more logical than '… in time of plague…' but I see neither as well-known in English

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin - Good! Thank you for this input.